# Maven build Error - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy (copy)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I am trying to execute the command mvn -clean install, I am getting the following build error

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy (copy) on project fxquotelogger: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:copy for parameter artifactItem: Cannot find setter, adder nor field in org.apache.maven.plugin.dependency.fromConfiguration.ArtifactItem for 'overwrite' -> [Help 1]

This is what I have in pom.xml contributing to the above error

```
<pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                                        <version>21.0</version>
                                        <type>jar</type>
                                        <overwrite>false</overwrite>
                                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/payload/temp/portware.dir.root/lib/external.war</outputDirectory>
                                        <destFileName>guava.jar</destFileName>
                                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                                        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
```

Edit:

In addition to the above error, I'm seeing the following error for "execution" in eclipse

Could not get the value for parameter artifactItems for plugin execution copy (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.1:copy:copy:package)

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter artifactItems for plugin execution copy
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.getMojoParameterValue(MavenImpl.java:950)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$6.call(MavenImpl.java:959)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.getMojoParameterValue(MavenImpl.java:957)
    at com.coderplus.utils.BuildHelper.processCopyOrUnpack(BuildHelper.java:166)
    at com.ianbrandt.tools.m2e.mdp.core.MdpBuildParticipant.build(MdpBuildParticipant.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at

Edit 2: It is resolved now. I had to close artifactItem and artifactItems above overWriteReleases

Comment: Looks like <overwrite>false</overwrite> is not a parameter in this plugin. Might be spelling overwrite to overWrite. Capital w

Comment: It is already in caps W

Comment: Sorry @kimy82, I have corrected it to caps W now, but still it is showing the same error

Comment: Have you had any luck since you posted this? Am getting this error since upgrading from Eclipse 4.9 to 4.11/4.12.

Comment: @Alexandros, take a look at my answer

Comment: Thanks. Mine was similar: I had to change <item> to <artifactItem> as that was the correct parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All, I myself was able to resolve this issue. The `<executions>` tag was closed before starting the `<configuration>` tag.

This is how the block would like.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>19.0</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/payload/temp/portware.dir.root/lib/external.war</outputDirectory>
                <destFileName>guava.jar</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
        <!-- <stripVersion>true</stripVersion> -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: According to the code, executions must be closed before configuration. But in the text before code, you describe that situation as erroneous.